# Is there a way to see why certain dependency of a package is needed?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, deb

I was about to install `mysql-client-5.5` package which has `debianutils` package as a dependency. However, I first checked which binaries are installed with `debianutils` package. It installs nine utilities: `savelog`, `ischroot`, `add-shell`, `remove-shell`, `which`, `tempfile`, `run-parts` and `installkernel`. Are any of those utilities really needed for `mysql-client-5.5`? Is the only way to check this by viewing the source code of `mysql-client-5.5` package or is there a more convenient method?

Comment: Was your question a general one, or a specific one about `mysql-client-5.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package maintainer lists the dependencies for a package when they create the specifications file. Looking at the list of what debianutils is it seems they use it to aid in the installation of the package, but yes, you would need to dig deep to find why it is a dependency. I'll bet you could find the usage of these tools in the ./configure script of the source tarball...

[Debinautils package description](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/debianutils)

Comment: A package used by the `./configure` script in the source tarball would be mentioned in the build dependencies, not the binary dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

There's no general answer. Sometimes you can find more information on a dependency in a package's description; this is more often true for "Recommends:" or "Suggests:" rather than full-blown "Depends:", to help users decide whether or not to install the weak dependency. Another source of information can be a package's changelog; that will sometimes indicate the reason for adding a dependency.

In `mysql-client-5.5`'s case, the dependency itself gives a clue: it's `debianutils (>= 1.6)`. Looking at [`debianutil`'s changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/d/debianutils/unstable_changelog) indicates that version 1.6 introduced `tempfile`, `sensible-editor` and `sensible-pager`. Restricting the search to those three in `mysql-client-5.5` reveals that the startup scripts use `tempfile`, which justifies the dependency on `debianutils`.